# Time doesn't correctly update in Unity Inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I run the game, Unity's inspector updates every few seconds, but `totalTimeElapsed` only increments in a series of 0.1 seconds. I tried a similar thing with `totalTimeElapsed += Time.deltaTime` but with the same result.

How do I get the total time since game start?

```
float totalTimeELapsed = 0;
int dayCount = 0;

private void Update()
{
    totalTimeElapsed = Time.time;
    dayCount += 1;

    AFunctionTakingLotsOfTime();
}
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen? What do `BeginDay`, `MidDay` and `EndDay`? What do you mean by `only increments in a series of 0.1 seconds`? From the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html): `This is the time in seconds since the start of the game.` and also `Try to avoid regular (frame) use of Time.time. It is more intended to supply the time the game has been running, and not time per frame.` .. so what is it you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Because `AFunctionTakingLotsOfTime()` takes a long time, you need `Time.realtimeSinceStartup`

[`Time.realtimeSinceStartup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html) deals in real time, rather than computed frame-rate-time amounts that are probably getting messed up due to the fact that your function takes a long time.

Alternatively you could use [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Note that both will not be affected by things like time scale and you may want to change your function to be less intensive, such as computing only a small chunk any given call (or by using a coroutine) or by splitting the method off onto a [Job thread](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystem.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
float totalTime = 0f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    totalTime += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

I believe what you are looking for would be something like this. Assuming this class is present on runtime of your game, you should have an accurate variable which can tell you the elapsed time since the game started.

You might also want to know that the update call occurs once per frame, ie. if you are running at 60 FPS update will be called 60 times in that second. You can try FixedUpdate which updates in real-time intervals instead.

Comment: `which takes you current FPS into account` isn't it exactly the other way round? `Update` is called every frame while `FixedUpdate` is called in fixed real-time intervals regardless what the FPS is.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work for functions that take a long time.